# How to get different queries (models) results with one statement? - laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, eloquent

Sorry if my title is confusing, not sure how to explain this within a line. Let's say I have a table with some columns and I have this

```
$model = Document::where('systemName', '=', $systemName)->where('ticketNumber', '=', ($nextTicketNumber))->get(); ticketNumber is unique where as there are quite a few systemNames
```

The above will get exactly what I want but I want more. I want an another array which will store all the rows under the same systemName. I know I can do this by doing

```
$allSystemNameModel = Document::where('systemName', '=', $systemName)
```

But is there a possible way to not having two variables and be easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't get both collections into one variable with one statement, however, you can create an array and store your results there:

```
$both = [];
$both['model'] = ...
$both['all'] = ...
```

UPDATE:

To avoid querying the database twice, you can use a `first` method that laravel provides us with.

```
$allSystemNameModel = Document::where('systemName', '=', $systemName);

$model = $allSystemNameModel->first(function ($doc) use ($nextTicketNumber) {
    return $doc->ticketNumber == $nextTicketNumber;
});

$both['model'] = $model;
$both['all'] = $allSystemNameModel->all();
```

Note:  Be sure to use `use` when working with php closures since `$nextTicketNumber` will be undefined otherwise.

Comment: ah ok....I thought since both queries is related to the column of `systemName` and since `$allSystemNameModel` pulls out all the rows with same 'systemName' that there might be away to use that array in `$allSystemNameModel` to get a an exact row needed so the code wouldn't have to go through into the database twice

Comment: @Dora, I can understand not wanting to query a database twice when you don't have to.  Luckily, laravel takes care of this for us via collections.  You would query for the `systemName` group and then filter to match a ticket number. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-filter

Comment: @Dora, I've updated my answer now that I better understand what you were going for.

Comment: alrighty ~ thanks.  sorry for the bad explanation I had.  Let me try this out, but the laravel version I have is 4.2.  Hopefully it's not just in 5.1 heh because I was then thinking maybe if I can do a `foreach` for `$allSystemNameModel` and loop through to find the matching `$nextTicketNumber` but haven't had the time to try it out yet

Comment: Yeah, it will work in a foreach like you suggested.  Of course, that is what happens behind the scenes with `first()`.  Hopefully you'll upgrade soon =)